# Rewrite Rule for Dynamic Image

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create an image generator with a path that looks like a normal image path. If the image is generated on the URL `http://example.com/img/gen/?v1=a&v2=b&v3=c&v4=d` I want it to be accessed from this URL: `http://example.com/img/gen/a/b/c/d.jpg`

I am trying with this `.htaccess` rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/img/gen/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /img/gen/?sn=$1&v=$2&ref=$3&t=$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have trying placing the file on `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/img/gen/` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a classical mistake which prevents your rule from getting applied. And though there still mighty be other issues you definitely have to understand that inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") the request URL is examined as a *relative* path. So your pattern trying to match an *absolute* paths can never match.

Instead implement your rule in a more flexible way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?img/gen/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ /img/gen/?sn=$1&v=$2&ref=$3&t=$4 [END]
```

Note the leading `11/?` which makes the leading slash optional. That way your implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).